# Iteration with variable name

Tags: c#, unityscript

Is it possible to make iteration from variables in c#? 
i have variables `public Transform dest1, dest2, dest3, dest4,...` and `public StudentScript stu1, stu2, stu3, stu4, ...;`and what i want is if collide with student1 then agent go to dest1 and callscript from stu1, if student2 then dest2 and stu2...

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
    if (hit.collider.name == "_student1") {
        Debug.Log (hit.transform.name);
        agent.SetDestination (dest1.position);
        if (Mathf.Abs (tagent.position.x - dest1.position.x) <= closeEnough && Mathf.Abs (tagent.position.z - dest1.position.z) <= closeEnough) {
            stu1.ResetStudentBehaviour();
        }
    }else if (hit.collider.name == "_student2") {
        agent.SetDestination (dest2.position);
        if (Mathf.Abs (tagent.position.x - dest2.position.x) <= closeEnough && Mathf.Abs (tagent.position.z - dest2.position.z) <= closeEnough) {
            stu2.ResetStudentBehaviour();
        }
    }else if (hit.collider.tag == "_student3") {
        ...
```

sorry for asking this beginner-like question

Comment: @NicholasV.: By reading online, taking a course, finding a mentor...  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm onboard with that. Wanted him to not feel like a question isn't welcomed because he considers it beginner.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The feature you want is called an "array". An array is *a collection of variables that is indexed by an integer position.*

```
public Transform[] destinations = new Transform[10];
...
destinations[0] = whatever;
whatever = destinations[9];
```

and so on.

Comment: Been a long time since I've seen an Eric Lippert answer here. In addition to this, you can alternatively use what is called a `List` in C#. A `List` is similar to an `Array` but with some added functionality such as `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear`, etc.